# Visual Studio F1 Help w/ Python

Tags: python, visual-studio

Coming from a C++ background, I often made good use of Visual Studio's F1 help functionality to instantly take me to a help page of a function for examples or more explanation. This saved me from having to google the function. Are there similar help pages for Python, as I am just starting to learn it. If nothing official, is there a extension that could serve the same purpose of easily getting help information from the press of one button(s)?

I am running Visual Studio 2017.

Thanks

Comment: Type "Python documentation" into Google. It's all there.

Comment: I guess my problem is then that its not completely obvious how to link that documentation available on that website into Visual Studio's f1 button

Comment: You don't need to link it into Visual Studio's F1 button. It's a trivial alteration to your workflow. Sorry, not seeing any actual "problem" here.

Comment: I am not here to discuss whether or not you think pushing one button vs having to alt tab, search and click is trivial to my workflow or not. I am wondering how to link the documentation into a one button press within visual studio. Thanks

Comment: Then, with those constraints, I'm afraid there is only one possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. [Visual Studio doesn't ship with Python documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/python/), and you cannot rebind <kbd>F1</kbd> to do arbitrary things.

Instead, you can use [the online documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/), or [download it](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html) in PDF, HTML or CHM form then open it when you need it.